# Code - How to "search in project"

Tags: code, search

In most editors it's possible to perform a search within the open folder/project. How can this be achieved with Code in Juno, if at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now possible. Access global search with `<Shift><Control>F`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the feature exists in Code yet. However, a simple workaround is:

1. Right-click the folder / project, select "Open in" > "Terminal"
2. Type in the command: `grep -Ril "text to search for" .`

That will list all the files containing that text. Some notes:

- `.` Means search from the current folder
- `-R` Searches recursively, not just files in the current folder
- `-i` Searches case-insensitively
- `-l` Prints just the file names, not showing the line of text it's in

**Update:** If you want to then open the files in Code, add `` `pwd` `` to the end, which will print out the full paths of the files. Then use the names like `io.elementary.code filename` to open it in Code.

---

If you need to find files with a particular name, you can use the same method to open the folder in Terminal, then run the following command:

1. `find . -name '*part of name*' -print`

If "part of name" is for example "list", that will match files named "todo list.txt". You can also use the following flags:

- `-type d` To search for only directories (folders)
- `-type f` To search for only files

Comment: Thanks Dane, but I moved away from elementary OS. There were so many issues with Juno, it was relly disruptive for my workflow. In the meantime I switched back to Pop!_OS, and smooth sailing ever since.